# Word position prediction with keras

Tags: python, keras

I am facing the following problem. I need to create a model to predict the product groups from product title. For each word in a sentence I need to predict the position of a word marked as a product. My dataset looks like this:

Input: product title (max 10 words), eg.

- “red adidas sneakers” (this is when there is one product in the product title) or
- “red adidas sneakers + white t-shirt” (this is an example when there are two products in title)

There may be more products in the title

Output: the position of product for each word in the title.

- E. g. for title:  “red adidas sneakers” word “”sneakers” indicates that’s a product. Other words are sneaker’s features. It’s on 3rd position do so the output would be a vector [3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].  So I am mapping features to the product (word to position of product)
- For title with 2 products:  “red adidas sneakers + white t-shirt” the output would look like this: [3,3,3,0,6,6,0,0,0,0]. mapping goes like this: (red=3, adidas=3, sneakers=3, +=0, white=6, t-shirt=6)

It seems like a category prediction problem but it is not. Two similar titles make different outputs: e.g. “adiadas sneakers red t-shirt white” gets [2,2,2,4,4,0,0,0,0,0] and if differs from [3,3,3,0,6,6,0,0,0,0]. The same word “red” gets a different prediction (2 and 3).

Therefore I have two questions.

1. Is there a known model that solves this kind of problem?

I came with an idea inspired by the attention mechanism to create a model with 2 encoders from the same title. Use some CNN architecture to embrace the word context.  And then make dot product of two encoded inputs and predict word positions.

```
embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_tokens, dimension)
input1_embeddings = token_embedding(embeddings)
input2_embeddings = token_embedding(embeddings)

# CNN layer.
cnn_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
    filters=100,
    kernel_size=3,
    # Use 'same' padding so outputs have the same shape as inputs.
    padding='same')
encoded1 = cnnlayer(input1_embeddings)
encoded2 = cnnlayer(input2_embeddings)
l = tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes=(1, 2))([encoded1, encoded2])
output = Dense(10, activation=”softmax”)(l)
```

Is this a reasonable way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't need to output the word position, but just the beginning and the end position of the product names.

`"red adidas sneakers"` should output `[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, ...]`, where 1 indicates the beginning and 2 indicates the end.

`"red adidas sneakers + white t-shirt"` should output `[1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, ...]`.

Then this would become a sequence to sequence prediction problem.
Any sequence modelling may work, such as [RNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) and [Conv1D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D).  I'm not sure if the idea of taking a dot product is a plus.

That being said, I also think approaches other than deep learning are worth considering, since named entity recognition software may already do a good job for your use case.

Comment: It is very nice redefinition of a problem. I will give it a try. Though I think seq2seq might need to learn a lot more then simple word to word attention.

Comment: On the second though I see some drawback to this idea. There are examples that could not be solved with this approach. For example “red sneakers sport-shoes” gives [1,0,2/1] so on the last position there should be 1 and 2 at the same time. I could introduce new class 3 for end and start of new group or use binary classifiation but it further complicates the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all categories in advance, I think you should be using NER (named entity recognition) and treating this as a category prediction problem.

Comment: I know all possible categories but they are not constant. Lets forget for a moment about context words and use simple MLP to classify the sentence  “red adidas sneakers”. It will use all words disregarding its position to predict 3rd possition (3). If we change sentence to  “adidas sneakers red” the same input will predict 2. So as you can see this introduces some noise and is contrary to regular NER classification when you move any NER the class moves with it. That’s why I think this is not regular time distributed classification. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: This should be a comment. It is too trivial to be an answer.